# Prevent a queue of events in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have made a GUI using TkInter.
Now I am trying to perform an action after a key press.
However, I don't want the action to perform twice when I click the button twice.
But rather, the program should wait until the previous action is finished before it starts waiting for the next key press.
I cannot seem to achieve this, even thought the command handler returns `"break"`.
See below a minimal working example, where if you press the `<Left>` button multiple times, the code also executes multiple times. How should I change the code to achieve the desired performance?

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self)
        # Create handler
        def event_handler(event):
            print('One run for event', event)
            time.sleep(1)
            print('Done')
            return "break"
        # Button
        self.button = tk.Button(
            master=self,
            text='Test',
            command = event_handler
            )
        self.button.grid()
        self.bind('<Left>', event_handler)
        self.focus()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("TestTool")
    # Start application
    app = App(root)
    app.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When You execute Your `event_handler` with `time.sleep(1)`, You are effectively blocking any other event execution. But event triggers are accumulating and executed one after another how each `event_handler` starts and ends. It creates effect of serial execution of `event_handler`.

What You want is to set some flag which will indicates Your event state. Then You have to process all accumulated events before Your `return` from `event_handler`. This will cause all events to execute, but immediately `return`, because flag is set to `True`: *event is running*.

Here is code snippet:

```
import time
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Frame):

    event_running = False

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self)

        # Create handler
        def event_handler(event=None):
            # Check if event is running
            if self.event_running:
                return False
            # Lock event until it's finished
            self.event_running = True
            print('One run for event', event)
            time.sleep(1)
            print('Done')
            # Update all pending events
            self.update()
            self.update_idletasks()
            # Release event handler
            self.event_running = False
            return

        # Button
        self.button = tk.Button(
            master=self,
            text='Test',
            command=event_handler
        )
        self.button.grid()
        self.bind('<Left>', event_handler)
        self.focus()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("TestTool")
    # Start application
    app = App(root)
    app.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: But what if there are 5 different `event_handlers`? Do I need to add the check and lines of code to all handlers?

Comment: You can create function `process_events` which will execute `update` and `update_idletasks`. And then it depends. If You won't use Threading for event execution, You will always block execution of other events until current event is finished. You can either create one `event_running` as a global flag allowing only one event execution. Or You can create specific flag for each handler. It also depends on how long is Your event execution. If it's more than few hundreds milliseconds, I would use separate Thread to execute them.